# external 2Tb usb disk not seen

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

I just have a new 2T usb external hard drive. I have Ubuntu 20.04 on a recent Lenovo ThinkPad machine. (I have installed exfat-utils exfat-fuse)

I plug in the drive into the usb port and nothing happens.

I see it with lsusb as

```
 Bus 001 Device 021: ID 048d:1234 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. Mass storage
```

but not with parted (nor gparted, fdisk, lsblk or anithing).

So I'm not able to mount the disk.

I checked the external drive on a windows machine and it works (seen as ExFat)

I tried all usb ports of my laptop but the result is the same.

How can I see the disk?

---

Here the outputs of some commands

dmesg gives something like:

```
[ 1410.288066] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd

[ 1415.511717] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[ 1431.126603] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[ 1431.362538] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd

[ 1436.506558] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[ 1452.117681] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[ 1452.225651] usb usb1-port3: attempt power cycle

[ 1452.881317] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd

[ 1458.133358] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[ 1463.509006] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[ 1463.744711] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd

[ 1468.884512] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[ 1474.260207] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[ 1474.368286] usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Comment: Do you see anything in Terminal with `lsblk`? How did you remove the disk from Windows? A "Safely remove disk" or straight disconnection?

Comment: I see the disk of the laptop with all its partitions

Comment: Check output of `sudo fdisk -l`. Check the kernel messages that appear while you plug in the drive: `sudo dmesg`

Comment: fdisk -l sees only the interal disk. I mean, it "sees" a lot of "/dev/loopN" but only the partitions of the interanl disk. I added the output of dmesg in the question

Comment: In 20.04's synaptic I see exfat-fuse & exfat-utils. Neither installed by default. Not sure if one or the other is the newer one. May now be in kernel?  https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=New-exFAT-For-Linux-5.7. You probably just need to install the driver. But if using Ubuntu better to use ext4. And make sure Windows fast start up is off. It sets hibernation flag preventing full mount from Linux.

Comment: Does the 2TB disk come with its own external power supply? If so, use it. If not, then you'll need a POWERED USB hub to use it. The other possibility is the use of USB3 devices when connected to a USB2 port, and there's a patch for that. How is your device connected?